# What is API-facing code?

Tags: api

so I'm wondering what does API-facing code mean? I have been googling it, but I can only see sentences with it, but not explanation for it...

Context: "The code supporting this article has been provided as a single Android app for illustrative purposes. In practice you should not distribute your server-side API keys in an Android app as your key cannot be secured against unauthorised access from a third party. Instead, to secure your keys you should deploy the **API-facing code** as a server-side proxy and have your Android app send requests via the proxy, ensuring requests are authorized."

Can you explain to me what API-facing code means? Thank you and I'm looking forward to your reply!

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "API-facing code" is the code that interacts with the API. They are suggesting the creation of a server component (proxy) that sits between Android and the API, so that the key does not need to be distributed with the Android app. (Instead the "in-between" piece on the server holds the key.)